# Change color of end of record in ListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-studio, scrollview

Is it possible to change the color of end of scroll in a listView.. When I scroll to the end of listview or beginning of listView I get white color in the top and bottom of end of scroll. Can I change that color?

Thanks!

Comment: show us what you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in your adapter getview function the getview function will called everytime a new listview item is show on screen. put below if else statement in your getview function

```
if(position == 0 || position == getCount()){
   // change to the color you want to change
} else {
  // change back to the normal color
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To chang color of last item,

```
if (position == list.length - 1) {
    holder.title.setTextColor(Color.RED);
}else{   
    holder.title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```